# nodejs upload file to S3 bucket via lambda function file content problem using aws sdk v3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, file-upload

I have a next.js frontend app,(you can consider that as Postman as well) and sending a multipart/form-data htpp request to an AWS Lambda function.

Lambda function is responsible to upload voiceFile to S3 Bucket. jsonText is not a problem in my case.

the request body is created by this code block (frontend)

```
        _formData = new FormData();
        _formData.append('jsonText', JSON.stringify(_bodyObject));
        _formData.append("file", voiceFile);
```

my lambda function:

```
 exports.handler = async (event) => {


    const result = await parser.parse(event);
    const fileList = result.files;
    const _fileItem = fileList[0];
    
    const _fileBody=  new Uint8Array(_fileItem["content"].buffer); 
    const length = _fileBody.length;
    const _contentType = _fileItem['contentType'];
    const _contentEncoding = _fileItem.encoding;
    
    const client = new S3Client({
        region: '',
        credentials = {
        "accessKeyId": 'accessKeyId',
        "secretAccessKey": 'secretAccessKey',
      }
    });
    
    const command = new PutObjectCommand({
      Bucket: 'bucketName',
      Key: 'someKeyHere',
      Body: _fileBody,
      ContentEncoding: contentEncoding,
      ContentLength: length,
      ContentType: _contentType,
  
    });
    const response = await client.send(command);

}
```

I have tried lots of variations for **Body in PutObjectCommand**. File is being uploaded but there are corruptions, or errors, or content is broken. Sometimes a voice file is uploaded but voice is discomposed etc.

I also tried  **'lambda-multipart'** package for parsing body file, but the result is very similar. Any file, .pdf, .wav, .docx etc can not be uploaded.

I expect your help, Thanks in advance

I have changed parameters of PutObjectCommand, tried to create stream from fileBody, but none worked. I can upload a file to S3 Bucket, but when I download it via AWS Console, the file is always broken, corrupt, or content is discomposed.

I also tried `const { Upload } = require( "@aws-sdk/lib-storage");`  But I faced with similar results